# Sagemaker Debugger service gives MissingCollectionFiles error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I followed the instructions in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/ml-explainability-with-amazon-sagemaker-debugger/ blog post. When I execute the following commands, I get an error.

```
from smdebug.trials import create_trial
s3_output_path = model.latest_job_debugger_artifacts_path()
trial = create_trial(s3_output_path)
```

Error message:

```
"MissingCollectionFiles: Training job has ended. All the collection files could not be loaded"
```

Is there any idea to resolve the error?

Comment: Any chance you've solved this?